# Could you send me the names/emails of…

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Is the following sentence correct?

> Could you please send me the *names/emails* of all people that need to receive this report

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Proofreading questions such as yours are not a good fit for this site and will be closed. However, if you are concerned about a specific aspect of that sentence, please [edit] your question to identify it, say why you are uncertain, and elaborate what you have researched and understood so far.

Answer (score 2):

I'd change it to "Would you please send me the names and email addresses of all people who need to receive this report?"   ("Email" usually refers to the electronic letter sent, not to the address.)